# Class property as ByRef argument not working

Tags: vba, pass-by-reference

I am using a function to modify a series of strings, passing them ByRef as arguments to the modifying function. The caller's string variables are all modified as expected but the one argument which is a class property does not change, should this be possible?
The essentials of the class are:-

```
Private cRptRef As String

Public Property Get TestRefID() As String
    TestRefID = cRptRef
End Property

Public Property Let TestRefID(Test_Ref As String)
    cRptRef = Test_Ref
End Property
```

The function for modifying the strings has the following declaration

```
Public Function GetTestFileNames(ByRef hdrFile As String, _
                                 ByRef calFile As String, _
                                 ByRef dataFile As String, _
                                 ByRef testRef As String _
                                 ) As Boolean
```

The call to GetTestFilenames is as follows:

```
If GetTestFileNames(HEADERpath, CALpath, RAWDATApath, _
                    ref) = False Then
```

All the string arguments are declared as global strings and are empty ("") before the call. After the call they typicaly have content like "d:{path to file{filename.csv}.
So all these statements in the function populate the target strings OK.

```
hdrFile = Replace(userFile, "##", PT_Rpt.Info.FindNode(TEST_REF_HDRsuffix).data, , , vbTextCompare)
dataFile = Replace(userFile, "##", PT_Rpt.Info.FindNode(TEST_REF_DATAsuffix).data, , , vbTextCompare)
calFile = Replace(userFile, "##", PT_Rpt.Info.FindNode(TEST_REF_CALsuffix).data, , , vbTextCompare)
```

But this statement fails to assign anything to its target string

```
testRef = Mid(userFile, InStrRev(userFile, Application.PathSeparator) + 1)
testRef = Left(testRef, InStrRev(testRef, "_") - 1)
Debug.Print "Class.TestRefID="; testRef
```

The Debug.Print statement prints the expected string, but the external reference is not affected. Is this something to do with it being a property?
The target string being `Class.TestRefID` in place of the testRef argument.
If I replace the class property in the argument list with a standard string variable, and then assign that to the class property then it I get the expected result, which seems unnecessary work.
Is there something I'm missing or is this not possible in VBA?

Comment: Why not just pass the class as an argument?

Comment: Please post examples of userfile strings

Comment: Also, I suspect Class.TestRefID compiles as an expression and you cannot pass an expression to a ByRef parameter.

Comment: honestly, if you're having issues, make a function that does the replaces you want, and call it 4 times. a little less "elegant" but gets the job done without having to worry about whether end result gets saves to a local variable or a class property.

Comment: Where is the code showing how `GetTestFileNames` is invoked? I can **guess** it's probably `GetTestFileNames obj.TestRefID, ...`, but I'm not seeing that in your post. If that's how you have it, then yeah @Freeflow has it right: you can't pass functions or members around in VBA, so `obj.TestRefID` is an expression that needs to be evaluated before **the result** is passed (ByVal) to the function - by passing in an expression, you're discarding the reference to the value this expression is referring to, hence passing the string `ByVal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A member access expression is an *expression* that must first be evaluated by VBA before *its result* can be passed around.

If I have a `Class1` module like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Foo As String
```

And then a quick caller procedure:

```
Sub test()
    With New Class1
        bla .Foo
        Debug.Print .Foo
    End With
End Sub

Sub bla(ByRef bar As String)
    bar = "huh"
End Sub
```

The `test` procedure will output an empty string.

The reason for this is because when you pass a member to a `ByRef` parameter of a procedure in VBA, you're not passing a reference *to the member* - you're passing a reference to *the value held by that member*.

So the *member access expression* is evaluated, evaluates to `""`, so `""` is passed `ByRef` to the procedure, which assigns it to `"huh"`, but the caller isn't holding a reference to the `""` value, so it never gets to see the `"huh"` string that was assigned.

> *If I replace the class property in the argument list with a standard string variable, and then assign that to the class property then it I get the expected result, which seems unnecessary work*

It's not unnecessary work, it's *mandated*, otherwise nothing is holding a reference to the result of the member expression.

Then again the *real* problem is a design issue, [pointed out by Warcupine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857225/class-property-as-byref-argument-not-working#comment100264770_56857225): the function doesn't want to byref-return 4 values, it wants to take a reference to this object, and assign its properties.

Comment: "The reason for this is because when you pass a member to a ByRef parameter of a procedure in VBA, you're not passing a reference to the member - you're passing a reference to the value held by that member."  Now I understand, thank you for your help.

Comment: @NigelH my pleasure! I'd still try to see if the function can't be made to *return* the object, rather than a `Boolean` - it wouldn't even need to be supplied as a parameter. And you could return `Nothing` where you would return `False`.

Comment: @NigelH also, feel free to mark this answer as "accepted" by ticking the hollow checkmark near the top of the post.

Comment: I appreciate there are many alternative solutions to the problem here, but my main reason for the post was to understand why my 'first attempt' did not work. I am eternally grateful to this platform for providing access to knowledge that seems hard to find. @Mathieu your answer duly and gratefully accepted.